# Virtual RAM folder in Ubuntu?

Tags: virtualization, ram, storage

I would like to have a folder mounted as temporary, which is actually my RAM. This is so that, for example, I could copy a movie into my RAM, unplug my external drive, and then watch it. Can this be done? Thank you :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.
Follow this procedure.

To make the folder you want to mount the ram disk to:

```
mkdir /mnt/ramdisk
```

Execute the following line to create a ram disk. The size can be whatever you like as long as it fits into your available memory.

```
mount -t tmpfs -o size=1024m tmpfs /mnt/ramdisk
```

If you want this to be permanent do the following steps:

Open this file in nano or in whatever your preferred editor is.

```
nano /etc/fstab
```

Add the following line to that file and save the file.

```
tmpfs       /mnt/ramdisk tmpfs nodev,nosuid,noexec,nodiratime,size=1024M   0 0
```

This line is supposed to be one uninterrupted line. Again size can be whatever you see fit.

Now reboot and you will have a ram disk.

Comment: Thank you so much! Could I somehow make this my /tmp/ folder?

Comment: Yes, that's entirely possible. Just change the'/mnt/ramdisk' part to /tmp and change size to an appropriate value. Note that if you run out of space, problems may happen. If you've lots of memory you can leave out the size parameter and it will be set to the default value.

Comment: Thank you so much :) Very quick question - how can I add that line on the end in bash? I have a script I use to move back onto machines, and I would like this to be automatic c:

Comment: I've never tried this idea. You can try to put the line starting with mount, mentioned above, in a script and call that script in the file /etc/rc.local but using the etc/fstab file is the usual method.

Comment: I was thinking I could just have a line such as `echo "tmpfs       /mnt/ramdisk tmpfs nodev,nosuid,noexec,nodiratime,size=1024M   0 0" > /etc/fstab` but I wasn't sure if this was a safe method (or even if I used the correct operator...)

Comment: That's about the same as the procedure I suggested above. If you reload /etc/fstab after doing this I think it should work.